# "ee.Algorithms.If" gives different value by NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I want to use `ee.Algorithms.If`. It gives different value by NDVI. I write code like this：

```
fsl=ee.Algorithms.If(ndvi1.gt(0.2),
                     0.92,
                     ee.Algorithms.If(ndvi1.lt(0.5),
                     0.99,
                     0.8))；
```

I want to use this Polynomial. If NDVI is less than 0.2, the grid value is 0.9, if NDVI is greater than 0.5, the grid value is 0.92, if NDVI is between 0.2 and 0.5, the grid value is 0.91.

I get the error `Cannot add an object of type <ComputedObject> to the map`.

Comment: And what happens when you run this?

Comment: Cannot add an object of type <ComputedObject> to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use this:

```
//Suppose *NDVI* is your original NDVI
var NDVI2 = NDVI.expression('b(0) < 0.2 ? 0.9 : b(0) > 0.5 ? 0.92 : 0.91')
```

**Update**

Based on your comments, one way is:

```
var FSL= NDVI.expression('NDVI < 0.2 ? 0.92 : NDVI > 0.5 ? 0.99 : IndFV', {
'NDVI':NDVI,
'IndFV':fv.multiply(0.02644).add(0.96356)});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you ,is useful. But actually my last condition need NDVI raster join the calculation 
`var NDVI2 = ndvi.expression('b(0) < 0.2 ? 0.92 : b(0) > 0.5 ? 0.99 : fv.multiply(0.02644).add(0.96356)`
how to use NDVI in this code

Comment: You're welcome. I don't understand your question. Please give me more details. Also providing your code might be useful.

Comment: I have a polynomial that calculates the surface emissivity FSL based on NDVI. When NDVI is less than 0.2, FSL=0.92; when NDVI is greater than 0.2 and less than 0.5, FSL=fv*0.02644+0.96356; when NDVI is greater than 0.5, FSL=0.99.

Comment: Thank you for your help